# How do I format following array/object

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am getting array/object by calling an api

If room types are more I am getting array like this

```
 [HotelRoomResponse] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [rateCode] => 203735593
                            [rateDescription] => Mango Standard
                            [RoomType] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@roomTypeId] => 766936
                                    [@roomCode] => 200163941
                                    [description] => Mango Standard
                                    [descriptionLong] => <strong><ul><li>One Twin Bed</li></ul></strong>This city view room measures 247 square feet (23 square meters). Complimentary wireless Internet access keeps you connected, and the 26-inch flat-screen TV offers cable channels. A coffee/tea maker is provided. The private bathroom has a shower with a rainfall showerhead, as well as complimentary toiletries. Climate control, air conditioning, and a ceiling fan are among the conveniences offered.  <p></p>
                                 )
                           )
                      [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        [rateCode] => 200928482
                        [rateDescription] => Mango Standard
                        [RoomType] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@roomTypeId] => 766936
                                [@roomCode] => 200163941
                                [description] => Mango Standard
                                [descriptionLong] => <strong><ul><li>One Twin Bed</li></ul></strong>This city view room measures 247 square feet (23 square meters). Complimentary wireless Internet access keeps you connected, and the 26-inch flat-screen TV offers cable channels. A coffee/tea maker is provided. The private bathroom has a shower with a rainfall showerhead, as well as complimentary toiletries. Climate control, air conditioning, and a ceiling fan are among the conveniences offered.  <p></p>
                             )
                        )

                )
```

If room type is only one I am getting following object

```
  [HotelRoomResponse] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [rateCode] => 1273814
                        [rateDescription] => Deluxe Double Room
                        [RoomType] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@roomTypeId] => 488629
                                [@roomCode] => 379721
                                [description] => Deluxe Double Room
                                [descriptionLong] => <strong><ul><li>2 beds</li></ul></strong>
                              )
                      )
```

I want to serailize the second object to first object i.e if we get more room types

How can I make above object to like this

```
 [HotelRoomResponse] => Array
                  (
                     [0] =>stdClass Object
                       (
                        [rateCode] => 1273814
                        [rateDescription] => Deluxe Double Room
                        [RoomType] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@roomTypeId] => 488629
                                [@roomCode] => 379721
                                [description] => Deluxe Double Room
                                [descriptionLong] => <strong><ul><li>2 beds</li></ul></strong>
                              )
                      )

                   )
```

Also check the issue here `http://developer.ean.com/docs/error-handling/special-cases/axis-net-json-issues/` I didn't have any solution for PHP.
Can any one help me.

Comment: Writing code would be a good start...

Comment: use [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) and [is_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) to check what you want to do with the data you get and act accordingly

Comment: How are you building that response in your API?

Comment: For multiple it's giving array. If there is only one it's showing single object. How can I write loop to work for both the situations.

Comment: You can also check the issue here `http://developer.ean.com/docs/error-handling/special-cases/axis-net-json-issues/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my optimized  solution

```
if(is_object($HotelRoomResponse)) {
    $NewHotelRoomResponse[0] = $HotelRoomResponse;
    $HotelRoomResponse = $NewHotelRoomResponse;
}
```